# Python Django models basics

Tags: python, django

I am learning django and trying to create a simple Question-Answer app where users can also like the questions and/or answers. Now what I want to do is track who liked a particular question/answer so I created a separate model for tracking this as follows:

```
class Votes(models.Model):
    answer_id = models.ForeignKey(Answers, related_name='likes_answers', null=True, default=None, db_column='answer_id')
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Questions, related_name='likes_questions', null=True, default=None, db_column='question_id')
    likes_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    liked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='like_user', null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now the problem with this approach is that everytime a question or an answer is liked there will be an entry to this model which will create multiple entries of same question_id or answer_id with different users. Although the users are different, but a lot of answer_ids and question_ids are getting repeated...Is that right approach or can I make it better?

Comment: Don't call them "answer_id" but simply "answer". Django will add the "_id" part automatically behind the scenes. Also, don't call it "liked_by" but "user" and the related name "likes", so you can do `user.likes.all()` etc. Same for the `answer` and `question`. Finally, the model should use singular always, so `class Vote(models.Model)` and not "Votes".

Comment: Thanks for the tip @C14L, I will take care of that. I used question_id because I am working with django rest framework serializers and I want to send this to client as a key in JSON. That is, {"question_id": <some_id>}. When I use question it's sent as {"question": <some_id>} which is confusing. Is there a way where the key is different from field name in serializers?

Comment: Yes, there is, and you should do the "naming" for your REST API fields in DRF and not on a database level.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to do it at drf level. I searched and read about this but couldn't find a solution to change the naming at serializer level. Thanks in advance!....Also, I have used liked_by because in future there may be a disliked_by too!!....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a better approach would be using many-to-many fields: users are able to like multiple questions/answers, and questions/answers may be liked by multiple users.

Assuming your Answer has a foreign key to a particular question, the models may look like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # .. other attributes
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'liked_question')

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    # .. other attributes
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'liked_answer')
```

To get all users that liked the answer, you use

```
 answer_object.liked_by.all()
```

For the (often-used) likes count, you would simply use

```
answer_object.liked_by.count()
```

Many-to-many fields work the other way around too, so to determine likes by a user, you may use (thanks to the related name)

```
user_object.liked_question_set.all()

user_object.liked_answer_set.all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @L Green. That definitely seems to be a better approach!

Answer (score -1):

It's not a python, django question, it's fit an RDBMS design question.

But to answer your question,

If you want to check the duplicate from voting by user then it's right approach.

Other approach is update the voting post id to the user table. It's of course bad approach.

Comment: Thanks @sayingu !!